# prove newton quadratic convergence

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

Trying to prove Newton's method quadratic convergence given the following:

Assume:

1. f is real valued function on open convex set S
2. ||$\nabla^2 f(x) - \nabla^2 f(y)$|| <= L||x-y||, Hessian is Lipschitz continuous on S
3. Sequence $x_k$ is generated by: $x_{k+1} = x_k - [\nabla^2 f(x_k)]^{-1} * \nabla f(x_k)$

The first part of the proof states:

Prove that:

$x_{k+1} - x* = \nabla^2 f(x_k)^{-1} * [\nabla^2 f(x_k)(x_k - x*) - (\nabla f(x_k) - \nabla f(x*)]$

I'm not sure how to go about proving the above.  I tried expanding $\nabla f(x_{k+1})$ about x* using Taylor approximation but that did not yield the above result.  I'm also not quite clear what the equation is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S$ is open and convex, the minimizer of $f$ will satisfy $\nabla f(x_*) = 0$.

Then, starting from the update $x_{k+1} = x_k - (\nabla^2 f(x_k))^{-1} \nabla f(x_k)$,
we can substract $x_* $ from both sides:

\begin{aligned}
x_{k+1} - x_* &= x_k - x_* - (\nabla^2 f(x_k))^{-1} \nabla f(x_k) \\
&= \color{blue}{\nabla^2 f(x_k)^{-1} \nabla^2 f(x_k) (x_k - x_*)}
- (\nabla^2 f(x_k))^{-1} \nabla f(x_k) \\
&= \color{blue}{\nabla^2 f(x_k)^{-1} \nabla^2 f(x_k) (x_k - x_*)}
- (\nabla^2 f(x_k))^{-1} (\nabla f(x_k) - \color{green}{\nabla f(x_*)}),
\end{aligned}

The part in blue is just rewriting $x_k - x_*$, and the part in green is due to
$\nabla f(x_*) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you.  Why if the set S is open and convex will the minimizer of f have a 0 gradient at a minimum?  The set S is convex but that does not speak to the shape of the curve of f?

Comment: Since the set is open, there is a ball of sufficiently small radius around the minimizer $x_*$ that is contained in the constraint set. If the gradient is nonzero at $x_*$, there must be descent direction $d$ such that $\langle \nabla f(x_*), d \rangle < 0$, which means that for small $t$ you will have $f(x_* + td) < f(x_*)$, a contradiction. To show the last claim, you can use the Taylor theorem.

Comment: Thank you.  One final question, in such a case you can dot the gradient with this directional vector such that its angle > 90 degrees as you state and thus the dot product is negative, but what if the set was constrained and not open, such as with a paraballoid?  How do we ascertain the feasible directions d of the function to ensure that f(x+td) remains on the function f()?

Comment: In that case, the typical strategy is to project back to the constraint set after taking a step. But, unless the set is convex, it becomes much harder to show that you are converging to something useful.

Comment: Hi I have a question that's a bit unrelated but is in the spirit of convex optimization.  The book says to prove that a quadratic function with PD hessian will converge in one iteration using steepest descent w/ exact line search if starting on a major axis of the ellipsoid contour.  Have you seen this before as this doesn't make sense how this can be proven?  Thanks!